# Execute commands within  tsql

Tags: sql-server-2008, xp-cmdshell

How can I execute system command like `dir` other than `xp_cmdshell`?

Comment: whats wrong with xpcmd_shell ?

Comment: Well it simply does not work - program that sends query does not responds after that, even if command is dir that does not take time to evaluate.

Comment: Have you tried the `xpcmd_shell` from SSMS?

Comment: I cannot try because i does not have direct access to server - only through that program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any problem  , here is an example :

*dstest* is a remote server ...

[image]

### edit

run this to activate :

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: Maybe this stored procedure(xp_cmdshell) is blocked?

Comment: Thanks! Even though i saw your edit in MSDN, only by reading it careully second time and executing commands one by one I achieved the desired result.